# read hbase from pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hbase

I am trying to read from hbase with pyspark.

- hbase version: HBase 1.2.0-cdh5.16.2
- pyspark version: version 2.3.0.cloudera4

I think I need to use this jar [hbase-spark-1.2.0-cdh5.16.2.jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hbase/hbase-spark/1.2.0-cdh5.16.2)

I downloaded it and run the code:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

app_name = "hbase"
spark = (
    SparkSession.builder.master("yarn")
    .appName(app_name)
    .config("spark.jars", "hbase-spark-1.2.0-cdh5.16.2.jar")
    .getOrCreate()
)


dataSourceFormat = "org.apache.hadoop.hbase.spark"

readCatalog = """{
    "table":{"namespace":"namespace_dev", "name":"logs"},
    "rowkey":"key",
    "columns":{
        "key":{"cf":"rowkey", "col":"key", "type":"string"},
        "ARTICLE":{"cf":"atlas_data","col":"ARTICLE","type":"int"}
    }
}"""

readDF = spark.read.options(catalog=readCatalog).format(dataSourceFormat).load()
```

but got the error:

> Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o87.load.
> : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.Logging was removed in Spark 2.0. Please check if your library is compatible with Spark 2.0

What I understand is that my current version is not compatible with Spark 2. Is it correct?
In that case, where can I find the same driver but available for Spark 2.X ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're using `spark.jars` and pass only the name of the HBase Spark connector.  But this connector itself depends on the big number of the jars, such as `hbase-client`, etc.  and classes from these jars aren't found, like, `TableDescriptor` that is in the `hbase-client` - because you didn't specify them.

You have several solutions:

1. Specify all dependencies explicitly in the `spark.jars` - but this could be cumbersome, as number of dependencies is high
2. Specify Spark HBase Connector via `--packages org.apache.hbase:hbase-spark:1.2.0-cdh5.16.2` when launching `spark-shell` or `spark-submit` - it's easier, but you may need to specify `--repository` as well to be able to pull Cloudera builds
3. Create a fat jar for HBase Spark connector with all its dependencies inside - but it should be done by yourself, as I don't see official "fat jar"

I personally would go with option 2...

Answer (score -1):

Spark version is 2.3.0, and the hbase-connector is for spark 1.2.0, just try to use from the maven central repository a newer version, like [this](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hbase/hbase-spark/2.1.0-cdh6.3.3).

Comment: it gave me another error : `Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o87.load.
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/TableDescriptor`

Comment: @dumitry apparently, but i may be wrong, the class `TableDescriptor` is related to hbase 2.x, therefore it does not exist in Hbase 1.2

Comment: @Steven What is the environment that you are trying to run the code (cloudera version, hive version, spark version) ?

Comment: @dumitry Using [CDH 5.16.2](https://docs.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/release-notes/topics/cdh_vd_cdh_package_tarball_516.html). We installed spark 2.3 on top of that.